# Python エラー'cp932' codec can't encode character

Tags: python

pythonでスクレイピングをしようとしています。
元ネタ
http://qiita.com/shizuma/items/9dbcfd9ebe6b988572f6
どうしても

```
cp932 codec can't encode character '\u014d'in position6: ilegal multibyte 
sequence
```

というエラーが帰ってきてしまいます。

別の記事も参考にして修正しようとしましたが、
http://qiita.com/narupo/items/663dafee9c2d20311083

```
i/o operation on closed file
```

という別のエラーが出てきてしまいます。

以下コードです。

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time

base_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'

url_list = ['List_of_Japanese_actors', 'List_of_Japanese_actresses']

all_names = []

for i in range(len(url_list)):
    target_url = base_url + url_list[i]
    target_html = requests.get(target_url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(target_html, 'html.parser')
    names = soup.select('#mw-content-text > h2 + ul > li > a')


    for k, name in enumerate(names):
        all_names.append(name.get_text())

    time.sleep(1) 
    print('scraping page: ' + str(i + 1))

f = open('all_names.csv', 'w') 
writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
writer.writerow(['name'])
for name in all_names:
writer.writerow([name])

f.close()
```

いろいろ試しているのですが、うまい解決策もなく質問させていただきました。
どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: pythonのバージョンはどうですか？ 2と3ではunicodeの扱いなどが違うので、アドバイスも変わってくるかもしれません。

Comment: 失礼しました。pythonは3.6.0です。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

環境は Windows で、 Python 3 をお使いということで宜しいでしょうか。また、例外の発生個所は `writer.writerow([name])` の箇所で合っておりますでしょうか。 **「お使いの環境の情報」** と、できるだけ省略せず **「そのままの例外出力(Traceback)」** があると回答がしやすいので、お留め置きいただければと思います。

さて、上記の推測が正しいとして、原因は例外で言われているように、 **CP932 という文字コードでは、 '\u014d' という文字が正しく扱えない** ことにあります。 [o の上に長音記号が付いた字](http://glyphwiki.org/wiki/u014d) ですね。

スクレイピング対象となるページは、ページによって様々な文字コードで作られていますが、そのままでは扱いづらいので、まずこれをデコードして Python 内部の Unicode 文字列表現に揃えてやります。ご呈示のコードでは、以下の箇所が該当します。ここまでは、特に問題がありません。

```
# `text` 属性へのアクセスは、受信したバイト列をデコードして文字列にする
target_html = requests.get(target_url).text
```

ただ、その後ファイルに書き出す時には Python の内部表現をそのまま書き出すわけにはいきませんので、何らかの文字コードでエンコードし、バイト列にしてから書いてやることになります。これは、実は以下の箇所が自動的に行っているのですが、この時 Python 3 はデフォルトの文字コードとして **実行している OS の言語環境の文字コード** を選択してしまいます。そして日本語の Windows では、その文字コードは CP932 と呼ばれるものになっています。

```
# テキストモードで開くと、自動的に実行環境の文字コードでエンコードされる
f = open('all_names.csv', 'w')
```

CP932 というのは、 Shift_JIS といった方が聞き覚えがあるかもしれません。 Shift_JIS に Microsoft が独自の拡張文字を追加したものを正確には CP932 と呼びます。この CP932 は日本語用の文字コードですから、問題となっている「ō」のような文字は表現できません。結果、 Python の内部表現からファイル用のバイト列に変換することに失敗し、処理がエラーとなって例外停止してしまいます。

ではこういった場合にどうするかですが、恐らく一番良いのは問題の文字をきちんと表現できる文字コードを指定してやることではないでしょうか。次のように、 `open()`関数に `encoding` キーワード引数を与えてやると、自動変換で使用される文字コードを直接指定することができますから、これを Unicode 文字が表現できる UTF-8 等にしてやればいいわけです。

```
# UTF-8 を指定してファイルを出力する
f = open('all_names.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')
```

あるいは、どうしても CP932 で保存したいのであれば、 `errors='replace'` や `errors='ignore'` を指定する方法もあります。これは正しく扱えない文字に遭遇したときに、 ? に置き換え (replace) たり単に無視 (ignore) したりするオプションです。ただ、これは情報が失われてしまうので、多くの場合望んでいる動作ではないと思います。

```
# CP932 で表現できない文字は ? に置き換える
f = open('all_names.csv', 'w', encoding='CP932', errors='replace') 

# CP932 で表現できない文字は無視する
f = open('all_names.csv', 'w', encoding='CP932', errors='ignore')
```

尚、このあたりの「バイト列である `bytes` と (Unicode) 文字列である `str` との関係」については、 Python 公式の [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.jp/3/howto/unicode.html) 等に詳しいので、ぜひ調べてみてください。

Comment: menew様、大変ご丁寧な解説並びに解決策をご提示いただきありがとうございます。現行のいくつかのコードではencoding='UTF-8'を指定することで問題なく稼働しました。大変ありがとうございます。

Comment: @Kojiro Ikedaさん  もしかして時間の問題等でできてないだけかもしれませんが、解決したら、回答に✔を付けて、質問をクローズしてくださいませ〜...

Comment: @cul8er すみませんでした。